# How to link to the Play Store "What's New" section in-app?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to link directly to the Google Play Store What's New section for my app (from within my app itself). There is no div id on that section to do this with url anchors.

Looking at the format of the play store url https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?, I am wondering if there might be something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/whatsnew?.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/new

Comment: No, I am referring to the "What's New" section of a single app.